# httpd [apache 2.4] memory leak issue

Tags: apache

Description of problem:
In our performance environment, we have observed the `httpd` memory usage have been increasing continuously over a time period, httpd process memory usage will increase from 6MB to 1GB over 10 hours and after stop load, memory usage for the process will not come down to 6 MB where it started from.

Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable):
using httpd-2.4.6-67.el7_4.6.x86_64 with RHEL 7.4 having

How reproducible:
trigger 1000 HTTP request per second

Steps to Reproduce:

Actual results:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 12314 notifs    20   0 5723112 2.101g    104 S 129.4 17.9 785:17.34 java                              
12582 notifs    20   0 5727148 2.082g      4 S 117.6 17.7 782:13.72 java                              
15509 notifs    20   0 3767700 1.009g    500 S  11.8  8.6  78:27.08 httpd                             
15511 notifs    20   0 3527984 984116    524 S  11.8  8.0  77:25.43 httpd                             
15510 notifs    20   0 3640620 964676    552 S  11.8  7.8  75:20.43 httpd                             
15504 notifs    20   0   77460    764    532 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.40 httpd
```

(note httpd started with ~6 MB and over 10 hours time reached to ~1GB).

Expected results:

No such memory leak

Additional info:

System (VM) is configured with 12 GB main memory and 4 GB swap, httpd eats all of them.

httpd is listen on 10180 (HTTP) only

Comment: And what does the page you request 1000 times do? What are the modules used per Apache? What server side techs. Is there a difference if you request static files vs dynamic ones? Plenty of elements are missing to fully understand the issue.

Comment: Also, if there's no programming involved at all, it's a question for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
List of Module :- 

LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule log_config_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so

LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so

LoadModule access_compat_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule mpm_worker_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule unixd_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

we are pumping post dynamic request from back-end server towards Apache server. 

Note :- same scenario was working in SLES 11 with apache 2.2 , but no`enter code here`w we are upgraded to RHEL 7.4 with apache 2.4 where we starting facing issue .

thanks in advance
```